# How to update channel subscriptions with ServiceStack + Redis?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

In ServiceStack w/Redis for pubsub, the "SubscribeToChannels(ChannelName)" call is blocking.  What would be the recommended approach for dynamically modifying which channels are subscribed to?

For example, if I have a list of thousounds of Persons, I want to do subscribe to changes for only "bob" (Person id=1).  Later, I might want to also monitor changes to "john" (Person id=2).

If I subscribe to changes for all users, then event will be triggered for all people changes, even if I only want to listen to a subset and invokes extra filtering.  On the publisher side, it implies I need to publish to channel names with the ID embedded, say publish("person:2").

A service that wants "all users" could subscribe to person:*

Will it be overhead to setup a type of "subscription factory" of sorts, that monitors new subscription requests (ie: person "john") and then spins up a new thread?

suggestions?

So far I am finding ServiceStack an excellent platform (Services + SQLServer ORM) and looking forward to integrating Redis for a notifications subsystem.